# What is the proper usage of "The... of..." and "A ... of ..."?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I wrote an article, and will submit it soon. I am troubled in its title:

"The Speedy Application of Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test for Stationarity Analysis with causfinder Package in R"

I have learnt that it would be better to add "the" to the beginning of "..of.." structures.

However, when I add it in my case, I am suspicious to have a grammar error caused by the relevant meaning in context.

I also thought to entitle it as:
"A Speedy Application of Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test for Stationarity Analysis with causfinder Package in R".

The some of the problem arises from the math'l theory:
There is no specific math theory I discovered now (or anyone else discovered earlier) that speeds up the calculation of ADF test statistics (like lowering the number of operations etc.). When I wrote "The", it seems to me that the sentence may mean like that as well.

I wrote some codes that bring together the works of others and reveals ADF statistics with less time by means efficient software coding.

"A Speedy Application of Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test for Stationarity Analysis with causfinder Package in R" reflects the meaning better, but it lacks the rule of putting "the" to the beginning of "..of.." structures.

Any idea?

Comment: **The "...of..." has no bearing on which article to use.** It's entirely about whether you're referring to one thing (There's only one speedy application, and you're talking about that) or one of a number of things (there's more than one speedy application, and you're talking about a particular one). If the duplicate question doesn't help, please edit this one to explain why.

Comment: 'A Tale of Two Cities' and 'The Tales of Peter Rabbit' both sold quite well.

Comment: I wonder why you use capitals for some words but not others. I also wonder whether there shouldn't be a *the* before *Augmented*, since *test* in this context is a countable noun and probably definite. The same applies to *the* before *Causfinder*, if it modifies *Package*, which is also probably a definite countable noun.

Comment: "of, for, with, in" are only connectives. In titles of article names, they are written with no capitals in general. In R, package names are unique. Hence, there is no possibility for another causfinder package, hence no "the".